# Set variable based on whether an exception is thrown or not in .NET application

Tags: c#, .net, variables

I have this `ConsumerBuilder` in a dependency package my application uses:

```cs
using var consumer = new ConsumerBuilder<byte[], byte[]>(config).SetErrorHandler(
    (consumeException, error) => throw new Exception($"KafkaTask Kafka error, Fatal:{error.IsFatal}, " +
        $"Code:{error.Code}, {error.IsBrokerError}, " +
        $"IsLocalError:{error.IsLocalError}, Reason:{error.Reason}")).Build();
```

I'd like to add something where if an exception is thrown, a variable is set to true. How do I do that?

Comment: By adding a `try` `catch` block.

Comment: Sure, set the variable before you throw the exception. You'll need to wrap the code in curly brackets (`{ variable = true; throw new ...; }`). Note that throwing an `Exception` is considered bad practice; you should a more appropriate derived type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add multiple lines to a lambda expression by enclosing them in curly braces:

```
var exceptionWasThrown = false;

using var consumer = new ConsumerBuilder<byte[], byte[]>(config).SetErrorHandler(
    (consumeException, error) => 
    {
        exceptionWasThrown = true;

        throw new Exception($"KafkaTask Kafka error, Fatal:{error.IsFatal}, " +
            $"Code:{error.Code}, {error.IsBrokerError}, " +
            $"IsLocalError:{error.IsLocalError}, Reason:{error.Reason}")
    }).Build();
```